# Trig-Which one of the following is in the domain of the function f(x)=log(sinx)?

Tags: trigonometry

Which one of the following is in the domain of the function f(x)=log(sinx)? You may use the fact that 1111 is just slightly greater than 353.64xpi)

so far i know the domain of 
sinx is (-infinity ,+infinity)
logx is (0, +infinity)

a)11 
b)111
c)1111
d)11,111
e) none of these

Comment: What is "the following"?

Comment: The domain of  $f(x)=\log(\sin(x))$ is the union of all the open intervals $]2n\pi,(2n+1)\pi[$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$ (Why?)

Comment: $f(11111)\approx -0.138763975945$ and the other given values are not defined (Why?)